# How to graph a horizontal number line with values? R

Tags: r, plot, statistics

Okay, my data looks like this

```
Product   Mean    Min    Max
  A       5.15     1      13
  B       6.13     3      8
  C       9.87     1      50
```

And I need to do a graph like this

Where the left value is Min and Right Value is max, and the green dot is the mean.

Do not take into account the "x" in the line

How can I do this kind of graph?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways, base R and `ggplot2`.

### 1. base R.

The points are plotted with `plot` and the bars with `arrows`.

```
y <- as.integer(as.factor(df1$Product))

plot(df1$Mean, y, 
     pch = 16, cex = 3, 
     col = "green", 
     xlim = c(-10, 60),
     ylim = c(0, 4),
     xlab = NA,
     ylab = "Product",
     yaxt = "n")
arrows(x0 = df1$Min, 
       y0 = y, 
       x1 = df1$Max, 
       length = 0.1,
       angle = 90, 
       lwd = 2,
       code = 3)
axis(2, at = y, labels = df1$Product)
```

[image]

### 2. `ggplot2`

The code is simpler, use `geom_pointrange` for the bars and overplot the points after.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(Mean, Product)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = Min, xmax = Max), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 6, colour = "green") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

If the lines at the end of the bars are needed, use `geom_errorbar`.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Mean, Product)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = Min, xmax = Max), 
                size = 1.5, 
                width = 0.25) +
  geom_point(size = 6, colour = "green") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Product   Mean    Min    Max
  A       5.15     1      13
  B       6.13     3      8
  C       9.87     1      50
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: yes the ggplot one worked pretty well, is there a way in ggplot to have the vertical little lines at the ends of the line?

Comment: @JorgeParedes Yes, there is, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you! It´s just what i needed